# GCD of successive terms

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, gcd-and-lcm

I was solving this question, and I'm hitting a wall.

> $a_n=20+n^2\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N,\quad d_n=\gcd(a_n,a_{n+1})$. Find with proof all values taken by $d_n$, and show by example when these values are achieved.

Here is my progress:

$\begin{align}d_n&=\gcd(a_n,a_{n+1})\\&=\gcd{(n^2+20,n^2+2n+21)}\\&=\gcd(n^2+20,2n+1)\\\end{align}$

I hesitate to multiply $2n+1$ by $n$, as if $n|20$ then it would increase the $\gcd$ by a factor of $n$.

How do I go further? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

If $d=(a_n,a_{n+1})$

$d$ must divide $$a_{n+1}-a_n=2n+1$$

$d$ must divide $$2(20+n^2)-n(2n+1)=40-n$$

$d$ must divide $$2n+1+2(40-n)=81$$

Comment: Thank you! So $d=1,3,9,27,81$. But is there a way to find out where these are achieved, without brute-forcing the terms?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo, If $d=1$ if $$3\nmid(2n+1)\iff 2n+1\not\equiv0\pmod3\iff 2n\not\equiv-1\equiv2\iff n\not\equiv1$$ etc.

Comment: If $81|(2n+1)$  $$\iff2n+1\equiv0\pmod{81}\equiv80\iff n\equiv40$$  Now $$(81d+40)^2+20\equiv0$$

Answer (score 1):

The extended Euclidean algorithm [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialextendedGCD%5Bn%5E2+%2B+20,(n%2B1)%5E2%2B20,n%5D)
$$
81= (2 n + 3)a_n+(1 - 2 n)a_{n+1}
$$
and so $d_n$ divides $81$. All divisors actually occur:
$$
d_0=1, \quad d_1=3, \quad d_4=9, \quad d_{13}=27, \quad d_{40}=81
$$
Here are the [values](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BPolynomialGCD%5Bn%5E2+%2B+20,+(n+%2B+1)%5E2+%2B+20%5D,+%7Bn,+0,+40%7D%5D) of $d_n$ for $n=0,\dots,40$:
$$
1, 3, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 27, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 81
$$